# Two twisted cubic curves in $\mathbb P^3$ intersect iff they lie in a common cubic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, projective-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be twisted cubic curves in $\mathbb P^3$. I want to prove that they intersect if and only if they lie in common cubic surface, perhaps singular. The second condition can be reformulated as $h^0(\mathbb P^3, I_{C_1 \cup C_2}(3)) > 0$.

Consider a short exact sequence
$$0 \to I_{C_1 \cup C_2}(3) \to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(3) \to \mathcal O_{C_1 \cup C_2}(3) \to 0,$$
and the corresponding long exact sequence of cohomology (all cohomologies are  over $\mathbb P^3$):
$$0 \to h^0(\mathbb P^3, I_{C_1 \cup C_2}(3)) \to h^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(3)) \to h^0(\mathcal O_{C_1 \cup C_2}(3)) \to h^1(I_{C_1 \cup C_2}(3)) \to 0.$$

We also know that $h^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(3))=C(6, 3)=20$ and
$$h^0(\mathcal O_{C_1 \cup C_2}(3)) \leq 2 h^0(\mathbb P^3, \mathcal O_C(3)) = h^0(\mathbb P^1, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(9))=20.$$
If cubic curves intersect, then $h^0(\mathcal O_{C_1 \cup C_2}(3)) < 20$, so indeed $h^0(I_{C_1 \cup C_2}(3)) > 0$ and that's all. On the contrary, if they do not intersect, $h^0(\mathcal O_{C_1 \cup C_2}(3)) = 20$, but there still may be $h^0(I_{C_1 \cup C_2}(3))$. Could you help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

If $C_1,C_2$ lie in a smooth cubic surface, we claim they intersect. Recall the cubic surface is blow up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at $6$ points. The class of twisted cubic $C$ in $\mathrm{Pic}(\mathrm{Bl}_6(\mathbb{P}^2))$ can be written as $al+\sum b_iE_i$, where $l$ is the class of a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$, $E_i$ are exceptional divisors. We know from Hartshorne V.4.8 that 
$$\deg C=3a-\sum b_i=3,$$ $$p_a(C)=\frac{(a-1)(a-2)-\sum b_i(b_i-1)}{2}.$$
So the possibilities are $$(a;\{b_1,\dots,b_6\})=(1;0,0,0,0,0,0),(2;1,1,1,0,0,0),(3;2,1,1,1,1,0),(4;2,2,2,1,1,1),(5;2,2,2,2,2,2),$$ which means $C$ is the strict image of a line passing through no blown up point, or a conic passing through $3$ blown up points, or cubic passing through $5$ points with a tangent direction, etc. Then one only need to show any two classes intersect. (Otherwise we get a contradiction to the conclusion.)